# Display no of days between two calendars

Tags: c#, user-controls, datetime-comparison

I want to calculate the difference between two dates and display it on the text box when TODATE is selected.

Automatically difference between FROMDATE and TODATE will display.

Note: Those calendars are user defined controls.

Comment: Show what have you tried..

Comment: i had code but the event for date change is not raising.if it is raised i thing i can compare dates

Comment: Which user defined it? He is the right person who can help you. We don't no what he has done in that, unless you provide some code.

Comment: [`DateTime.Subtract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx), [`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) Method as below

```
TimeSpan span = TODATE.Subtract ( FROMDATE );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

Comment: i want to write it when event is generated but i dont know how t ogenerate event for that

Comment: Use your calender controls Date selected event.. It is very useful post your code here..Otherwise people cannot give exact answers.